# HTML5 Top Down Racing Game

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, paperjs, pathanimator

I am creating an HTML5 based top down racing game and in order to get the cars around the track, I've looked into using two potential solutions (which I have working to an extent):

1. Paper JS
2. Pathanimator

I have got these both working individually in the sense that I can get objects moving around a path but the stumbling block I have is that each car will have its own starting position on either side of the race track (so won't always start at the same point within the path). The cars will also need to go single file after the first corner.

Another factor is overtaking. I have managed to use some Javascript to work out when two objects intersect, but need to make the object behind effectively "go around" the one in front and then back onto the racing line.

Quite a lot to work out here but wondered if anybody has some cunning ideas to make any of the above work?

Your help would be most appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically pathfinding works stateless; it doesn't matter which starting point you pick. The purpose is actually defeated if the algorithm used, cannot take a general point as the starting value. I'm not involved in those you mentioned though, they might support it.

If you structure only one possibly path around the track, then each car will follow. To be able for cars to begin in separate tracks, you can just offset their positions by a scalar, such as their car number. That is, offsetting the position from the path, relative to the course (emulating a track change).

To make them all choose the same track then, is as simple as having one point telling "now goto same track", which will set the scalar to 1 for everyone.

For overtaking, you would typically calculate the linear distance between two cars, using [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), when Car A gets close to Car B, Car A's offset scalar gets set to Car B's offset + 1, which will make it choose the outer track. This transition would of course be interpolated/extrapolated to give a smooth experience. Then when it has passed, reset to 1 again.

Answer (score 0):

You need a clear coordinates system to avoid confusion.
In this case, you should have 'x' as the distance from the starting point to the current position's basePoint.
And y the shift, locally perpendicular to the curve, between the car and the curve.

This way, a lot of things gets easier to see/do.
If y = 0, you know car in on the center curve.
To know if you can overtake, you'll have to do some math with ( overTaker.y +- overtaker.width/2 ,  overTaken.y +- overTaken.width/2, roadWidth).
In fact a regular BBox test using this coordinate system should be enough to test for collisions.